# Java compiler gets confused when passing overloaded method reference to an overloaded method

Tags: java, method-reference

I'm encountering some weird behavior when passing overloaded method references to a method overloaded with a `Function` and `Supplier` variant:

```java
public class OverloadedMethodReferenceToOverloadedMethod<X, Y> {

    public void method(Function<X, ?> f) {}
    public void method(Supplier<?> s) {}

    public void methodFunction(Function<X, ?> f) {}
    public void methodSupplier(Supplier<?> s) {}


    class NonMatchingOverload {
        public NonMatchingOverload() {}
        public NonMatchingOverload(Y overload) {}
    }

    class MatchingOverload {
        public MatchingOverload() {}
        public MatchingOverload(X overload) {}
    }


    public void foo() {
        // (1) This does not compile: the compiler complains about a mismatch in argument list length
        methodFunction(Object::new);

        // (2) This does not compile: the overload's parameter of Y does not match the Function's expected parameter X
        methodFunction(NonMatchingOverload::new);

        // (3) This compiles: the compiler correctly matches the overloaded constructor to Function
        methodFunction(MatchingOverload::new);

        // (4) These compile: we can pass the empty constructors as Suppliers
        methodSupplier(Object::new);
        methodSupplier(NonMatchingOverload::new);
        methodSupplier(MatchingOverload::new);

        // (5) This compiles: the compiler matches Object's only (empty) constructor to the overload with Supplier
        method(Object::new);

        // (6) This correctly does not compile: since both overloads match a constructor this is an ambiguous reference
        method(MatchingOverload::new);

        // (7) This (incorrectly?) does not compile: the compiler thinks this is simultaneously an 'ambiguous' and 'invalid constructor' reference...
        // Ambiguous because it thinks both the Function and Supplier overload match (like the previous example)
        // Invalid because it turns out it can't convert the non-empty constructor's parameter of Y to the expected Function parameter of X...
        method(NonMatchingOverload::new);

        // (8) These do compile: when explicitly typing the constructor reference as Supplier the compiler manages to match the correct overload
        Supplier<NonMatchingOverload> sup = NonMatchingOverload::new;
        method(sup);
        method((Supplier<NonMatchingOverload>) NonMatchingOverload::new);
    }

}
```

Statement #7 is where both the compiler and myself get confused: how can a reference be ambiguous if one of the two options turns out invalid? Am I doing something crazy, or is the compiler just not smart enough to figure out that only one valid option remains?

The behavior of the compiler for statement #2 is also strange to me, I would have expected the compiler to dismiss the overload with the parameter and complain about argument list length again. Could this have the same root cause as the strange behavior for #7?

Please note that this behavior is the same (but less concisely demonstrated) with regular method references, non-inner classes and without the use of generic `X` and `Y` types or the wildcards for `Function`.

(Bonus question: can anyone come up with a better name for a test class like this?)

Comment: `NonMatchingOverload` and `MatchingOverload` are both inner classes. This means that their constructors implicitly have an extra argument, which has the type of the outer class. The errors make sense when you consider that the overloaded constructors have 1 and 2 arguments, instead of 0 and 1 arguments.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt An interesting theory, but (unfortunately?) non-inner classes behave in the exact same way. I've added this to the question :)

Comment: Your question is very broad and it's unclear what you're actually asking. Taking the first one "(1)", it's clear why this gives an error, as the constructor for `java.lang.Object` doesn't take any arguments, so it cannot be a `Function` which takes one argument. Which of these 7 ones are you confused about, and which ones behave as you expect? Are you only confused about 7? Or also about 2?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm mainly confused about #7. While investigating I noticed #2's strange behavior, although it leads to the correct result in the end. I suspect #2's and #7's strangeness are related somehow. My question is very simple: am I missing something or is this a fault in the compiler?

Comment: That’s a known (intentional) limitation. You can not call an overloaded method passing a method reference to an overloaded method. You may be able to see which of the n×m combinations makes sense, but the compiler won’t. There has to be a cut somewhere. I don’t know what you mean with “#2’s strangeness”. The compiler is entirely correct in saying that X is not Y.